# PHP get next wednesday of a specific date

Tags: php

```
$wed_date = strtotime('next wednesday');

$my_time = $some_unix_time; 

//how do I get this line below to work
$the_next_wednesday_from_my_time = "";
```

e.g I want to know from a unix time, the next wednesday is when, how do I achieve it :)

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve difference between your time and next wednesday?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$currentDate   = time();
$nextWednesday = strtotime('next wednesday', $currentDate);

echo date('d-m-Y', $nextWednesday);
```

strtotime takes a second parameter which is the starting time. 
See https://php.net/manual/ro/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Why would this make a difference? If you omit the second parameter, it's already `time()` by default.